How do I view my notification history on iOS?
Earlier today I noticed a notification appear in my iPhone's Notification Center. At the time I had something to do, so I didn't check it right away. A few minutes later, I went to check the notification center only to find the notification was gone before I had a chance to read it.
Is there a way to check my previously received notifications on iOS?

Once you clear a notification from the notification center, you can no longer see it there. And there is no way to see cleared notifications on your iPhone either.
In this case, what you can do is to enable notification badges for the apps. The red dot and number on app icons will indicate you that a certain app has unread notifications and you can open the said app to see it.
Open Settings and go to Notifications. Choose the app for which you want to turn on badges.
Tap on the toggle of Badges to turn it on. This will possibly ensure that you see there is a notification after you clear them.
Another way is to turn of scheduled summary
Open Settings > Notifications > Scheduled Summary. Turn it on.
